# Complex Join in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have following senario

table1 - having 1 record with 1001(primary key)
table2 - having 3 record with same id (1001) - not as primary key
table3 - having 3 record with same id (1001) - not as primary key

The join of the first 2 tables is returning 3 rows (it is fine). But, if I join table3 then it is returning 9 rows. I know how join work and result is expected.

I need only 3 rows in result. something like shown below

```
 id      name     age     sex      city     
1001     Jhon      20      A        Z  
1001     Jhon      20      B        Y
1001     Jhon      20      C        X
```

[Here is fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d9/9)

Comment: Prepare please a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) example, you will have your answer much faster.

Comment: What is the relationship between table2 and table3? How do you know which of the three values of table3 you should select for the first value of table2? If you don't then 9 rows is the correct number.

Comment: are records just being duplicated would a distinct or group by resolve the issue? sample data would help along with expected results.

Comment: In order to get this you have to make a decision on sex and city. What logic have you used to decide that city Z is associated with sex A?

Comment: sex and city are independent. they can be any combination. both depends upon id 1001 not on each other. Hope I cleared.

Comment: No, you didn't clear it up. You only want one of 3 possible options. If they're independent and there is no decision to be made you get 9 rows. If you want 3 rows you need to make a decision. If you can't make a decision the you don't want 3 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a506d/9) may do what you ask for. To change the combination between Table2 and Table3 you can work on the two ORDER BY clauses. Really strange requierement anyway! Are you sure you're doing it right?

```
with ord_t2 as (
    select idt1 as id, sex, row_number() over(partition by idt1 order by sex) as ord_no
    from table2 t2
  ), ord_t3 as (
    select idt3 as id, city, row_number() over(partition by idt3 order by city) as ord_no
    from table3 t3
  ), t2_x_t3 as (
    select id, sex, city
    from ord_t2
      natural full outer join ord_t3
  )
select *
from Table1
  natural left join t2_x_t3
```